# Need help using json-framework on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

So I've got json-framework up and running on my project, but need help figuring out how to use it to parse this json string:

```
[
    {
    "id":"0",
    "name":"name",
    "info":"This is info",
    "tags":
        [ 
            {
            "id":"36", 
            "tag":"test tag"
            },
            { 
            "id":"37",
            "tag":" tag 2"
            } 
        ],
    "other":"nil"
    },
    { 
    "id":"1",
    "name":"name",
    "info":"This is info",
    "tags":
        [ 
            { 
            "id":"36",
            "tag":"test tag" 
            },
            {
            "id":"37",
            "tag":" tag 2"
            } 
        ], 
    "other":"nil"
}
```

]

Any help and maybe sample code on how to go about this **specific** type of json would be great. Somehow I can't get it into a dictionary I can read out of. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you can't get this string into a dictionary is because **it isn't a dictionary**, it's an **array of dictionaries**

You can get the values into an Objective-C object by storing it in an NSArray:

```
NSArray *objects = (NSArray*) [jsonString JSONValue];
```

Then, you can loop over those objects that are in the array:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in objects) {
    NSString *id = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *name = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSArray *tags = (NSArray *) [dict objectForKey: @"tags"];
    //loop over tags here...
    for(NSDictionary *tag in tags) {
        NSString *tag_id = (NSString *) [tag objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *tag_name = (NSString *) [tag objectForKey:@"tag"];
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I probably can't thank you enough for showing me this. I'm really new to json parsing and all and up 'till now I've had a hell of a time finding a tutorial or anyone to help me. Thanks.